# translating within PHP using WPML

Tags: php, wordpress, translation, wpml

I'm currently going through my static template files on a Wordpress-based website using WPML and wondering how I would set this PHP code up to be translatable:

```
<?php echo preg_replace("/href=\"([^\"]*)\"/", "href=\"$1#activity-filter\"", get_next_posts_link('Next Activities &raquo;')); ?>
```

Specifically the "Next Activities" text.

Currently I'm wrapping other lines of HTML like so:

```
<p><?php _e('Words that are being translated', 'roots'); ?></p>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would go like:

```
$translate = __( 'Next Activities &raquo;', 'roots' );
echo preg_replace(
    "/href=\"([^\"]*)\"/", 
    "href=\"$1#activity-filter\"", 
    get_next_posts_link( $translate )
);
```

Use this approach when the code is too intricate.

Related:

- [I18n for WordPress Developers](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers)
- [Best practices for localizing WordPress content?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1552/12615)

Comment: Awesome thanks. I'll give this a shot and let you know how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the help with this brasofilo. It works beautifully.

I just have one question, in the rest of my template files I'm localizing text by: 

`<?php _e('Words that are being translated', 'roots'); ?>`

When I do the code you helped me out with, and replace `<?php __(); ?>` with `<?php _e(); ?>` the code doesn't work. I guess I'm just wondering why? Thanks again!

Comment: The function `_e()` prints (`echo`) the string, whereas `__()` returns the value for you to store/manipulate. Check the documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers. Don't forget to check the page [about] for an introduction to Q&A. And the guide [help], for clearing other doubts. Also, there's a dedicated WP sister site: [wordpress.se] ;)

Answer (score -2):

Wordpress does not allow you to include php in your pages by default, however there are plugins such as [Exec-PHP](http://wordpress.org/plugins/exec-php/) which will allow you to do this.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm going through my template files (.php files). I'm not doing this directly in the editor window in the backend of Wordpress. Thanks though.